# Share CursorAdapter instance between Activities

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have an activity that loads result from the database using ContentProvider and LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface and displays in a list. It works fine no major problems so far. 
Now I want to display detailed view in another activity after clicking on the list item, I was thinking that if I already fetched the data I could share the CursorAdapter instance and this way have it reused and make possible to change content from within the DetailedView by flick gesture.

- Q: Is it possible without leaking memory in the application?
- Q: If not then how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can put them in a singleton instance  (ex : DataManager.class) and access them statically. For example you should kno about the Application singleton, it is a possibility

Comment: Yes Application was my first thought, but then I will have to create adapter in the Application and share instance in the activities. Also if adapter is used in list via setAdapter isn't it "bound" to it so it can leak?

Comment: It can't "leaks". The garbage collector do the works for you. Plus if you have them static in the Application var (or any singleton) you can refresh them from everywhere. It is references that you use want instanciating them in local var.